# LC-3 Instruction Understanding

Tags: lc3, lc3-trap

Hey Stackoverflow I was going over some example code our professor has left us to study with, and I've had some problems understanding what some of the codes mean and it doesnt help that some of his comments are vague. the first is R3,R1,0; check for end of line, the second thing I dont get is really the logic behind the beginning of the placeolnul, and lastly the .fill values for negeol which seem oddly specific but i have no idea why. if you could really help me with those issues it would really help me understand the code alot better.

```
 .orig x3000
    getstring:
     lea r0,prompt ;get string prompt
     puts
     ld r1,negeol ;to test end of line
     lea r2,rdbuff ;prep to read string
    rdloop:
     getc ;get string char
     out
     str r0,r2,0 ;store it
     add r3,r1,r0 ;check for end of line
     brz placeeolnul ;if so process
     add r2,r2,1 ;ready for next char
     br rdloop ;get it
    placeeolnul:
     and r0,r0,0 ;overwrite eol with
     str r0,r2,0 ;nul

     lea r1,rdbuff ;get address for len
     jsr strlen ;get length
     add r0,r0,0 ;if 0
     brz quit ;then prog finished
     trap xfc ;print length
     lea r0,colon ;print colon
     puts
     lea r0,eol ;print lf
     puts
     br getstring ;go again
    quit
     halt
    prompt: .stringz "Enter a string:"
    eol: .fill x000d ; or x000a
     .fill x0000
    negeol: .fill xfff3 ; or xfff6
    colon: .fill x003a
    rdbuff .blkw 80

    ; length subroutine
    strlen:
     and r0,r0,0 ;counter for length
     st r2,saveX2 ;save regs used
     st r3,saveX3
     add r2,r1,0 ;copy of string addr
    cloop:
     ldr r3,r2,0 ;get char
     brz exit ;check for nul
     add r0,r0,1 ;incr counter
     add r2,r2,1 ;go to next char
     br cloop ;process it
    exit:
     ld r2,saveX2 ;restore used regs
     ld r3,saveX3
     ret
    saveX2: .blkw 1
    saveX3: .blkw 1
    .end
```

Answer (score 0):

In regards to this:

```
add r3,r1,r0 ;check for end of line
```

Here he is setting up for the subsequent "brz" to branch on zero.

So we are adding the contents of registers r1 and r0 and putting them in r3, so that if r3 is zero, we will branch in the next line:

```
 brz placeeolnul ;if so process
```

Remember that r1 is already pre-loaded with a value based on this code:

```
ld r1,negeol ;to test end of line
```

which has loaded r1 with the value at the tag negeol per this code:

```
negeol
    .fill xfff3 ; or xfff6
```

So this is just a quick way to detect if an EOL character has been found by adding the compliment of the EOL character, which presumably here is xfff3.

Regarding the brz statement and the logic for it (your 2nd question):

```
brz placeeolnul ;if so process
```

As mentioned, we are branching here if the add is zero.  If we do not branch (meaning we did not find a EOL character), then we will continue, but that continuation will essentially loop back to rdloop tag:

```
 add r2,r2,#1 ;ready for next char
 br rdloop ;get it
```

If we DO jump via the brz line, that means we got the entire string, and we are ready to process it.... so jumping to placeeolnul  just puts us into the code where we can process the string:

```
 and r0,r0,#0 ;overwrite eol with
 str r0,r2,#0 ;nul
 .... etc...
```

Not sure if you have questions with this part of the code as well.

Hope this helps.

Jeff